# The first parameter of the select call is the maximum value of the incoming fd to be listened to plus one

Tags: linux, sockets, select, networking

I want to know why the first parameter of the select call is the maximum value of the incoming fd to be listened to plus one.

```
int select(int maxfdp1, fd_set *readset, fd_set *writeset, fd_set *exceptset, struct timeval *timeout);
```

As I see in some articles, if I let `fd_set` have 8 bits and `fd=5`, after I do `FD_SET(fd,&fd_set)`, the `fd_set` becomes `0001,0000`. However, if I let `fd=0` and do the `FD_SET`, what is the result?

Comment: You are asking two different and unrelated questions, and as such they should be posted separately. StackOverflow guidelines state 1 question per post.

Comment: Sorry. But I don't think they are irrelevant. The reason for adding 1 to the maximum may be because of the answer of my second question. I do not know whether it is true.

Comment: I didn't say they were irrelevant. I said they were unrelated. They should have been asked separately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. fd_set is bitmap which only represent 1024 fds at its maximum, the system will traverse fd_set from 0 to 1023 every it's notified, the parameter maxfdp1 (nfds) specify the upper limit, which limit the fd_set range, then the system check fd_set from 0 to maxfdps.

   - refer this [example](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzab6/xnonblock.htm), check how the max_sd is iterated.
2. Each process has its own opened file descriptor namespace(0,1,2 is `stdin, stdout, stderr`), `FD_SET(0, &fd_set)` will notify the process that `stdin` has incoming data.

Comment: The parameter was defined in the Berkeely Sockets API in about 1982 long before Linux even existed.

Comment: @EJP you are right, what I want to say is that it's implemented by OS authors